# manually create ggplot legend when plot built from two data frames

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am using ggplot to create two overlapping density from two different data frames.  I need to create a legend for each of the densities.

I have been trying to follow these two posts, but still cannot get it to work:

[How to add legend to plot with data from multiple data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58789168/how-to-add-legend-to-plot-with-data-from-multiple-data-frames)

[ggplot legends when plot is built from two data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38907371/ggplot-legends-when-plot-is-built-from-two-data-frames)

Sample code of what I am trying to do:

```
df1 = data.frame(x=rnorm(1000,0))
df2 = data.frame(y=rnorm(2500,0.5))

ggplot() +
  geom_density(data=df1, aes(x=x), color='darkblue', fill='lightblue', alpha=0.5) + 
  geom_density(data=df2, aes(x=y), color='darkred', fill='indianred1', alpha=0.5) +
  scale_color_manual('Legend Title', limits=c('x', 'y'), values = c('darkblue','darkred')) +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(pch = c(21, 21), fill = c('darkblue','darkred')))) +
  theme(legend.position = 'bottom')
```

Is it possible to manually create a legend?

Or do I need to restructure the data as per this post?

[Adding legend to ggplot made from multiple data frames with controlled colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46433741/adding-legend-to-ggplot-made-from-multiple-data-frames-with-controlled-colors)

I'm newish to R so hoping to avoid stacking the data into a single dataframe if I can avoid it as they are weighted densities so have to multiply by different weights as well.

Comment: What exactly did you try from those posts? You cannot get a legend for something you haven't mapped in an `aes()` call. You would need `geom_density(data=df1, aes(x=x, color="x"), ...)` for your first one and `geom_density(data=df2, aes(x=y, color="y"), ...)` for your second (since those are the limits you used in the color scale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike `x`, `y`, `label` etc., when using the density geom, the `color` aesthetic *can* be used within `aes()`. In order to accomplish what you are looking for, the `color` aesthetic needs to be moved into `aes()` enabling you to utilize `scale_color_manual`. Within that, you can change the `values=` to whatever you like.

```r
library(tidyverse)
ggplot() +
  geom_density(data=df1, aes(x=x, color='darkblue'), fill='lightblue', alpha=0.5) + 
  geom_density(data=df2, aes(x=y, color='darkred'), fill='indianred1', alpha=0.5) +
  scale_color_manual('Legend Title', limits=c('x', 'y'), values = c('darkblue','darkred')) +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(pch = c(21, 21), fill = c('darkblue','darkred')))) +
  theme(legend.position = 'bottom')+
  scale_color_manual("Legend title", values = c("blue", "red"))
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>